# Cannot find scale bar tool

Tags: qgis, scale-bar, toolbox

I am new to QGIS and I am working with version 3.22.5. I am trying to add a scale bar to a map. According to web tutorials, there should be a scale bar tool available. However, I cannot find it anywhere.

Is it possible that I am not displaying the whole toolbox?

Comment: Try View - Decorations - Scale bar if you want to add it into a map field. If that is not  your aim, please describe what it is, and what tutorials you have followed.

Comment: If you want to add a scalebar to a map layout there is a button for it but you can also use the Add Item menu.  If you want to add it to a map view then try user30184's suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scale bar is located, on the layout view (main view) here on the top menu:

[image]

However, if you are looking for the scale bar in the Print Composer view, it is located on the left-hand side menu, here:

[image]